# Debugger.Launch() not working in Visual Studio with Windows 10 Machine

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, windows-10

While working on a task, came across a situation where I have to put in **System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()** to automatically invoke the debugger on site's first load.

However, the option didn't work. I have searched many forums, all the references related to this on Stack Overflow and also tried few of the given solutions, unfortunately nothing worked for me.

*It was working for me when I was using Windows 7 prior to upgrading my machine to Windows 10.*

Is there any workaround or an alternative way to invoke the debugger automatically in visual studio?

**Note:** I am using Visual Studio Premium 2012 Update 5

Any pointers around this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!